# add background image in active class css bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs. I want to use a down arrow for active class on tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="font-size:20px;">
                  <li><a  class="active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sound-dolby"></span></a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

Here is css of active class.

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
    color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: url('../image/down.png') no-repeat !important;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

Right now its just displaying white background for active class. 
But not the image. 
Kindly help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in css class. You assigned it to anappropriate selector.  In html class assigned to  tag, but in css to

. You need to wright correct css rule.
So your code will looks like this:

```
.nav-tabs>li>a.active {
    background: #fff url('../image/down.png') right center no-repeat ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try this--

**Working snippet**

```css
 .nav li.active  {  
    
    cursor: default; 
    background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg') no-repeat !important;
     background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="font-size:20px;">
                  <li><a  class="active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sound-dolby"></span></a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
```